# Removing duplicates with ignoring case sensitive and adding the next column values with the first one in pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
Name    Count
Ram     1
ram     2
raM     1
Arjun   3
arjun   4
```

My desired output df,

```
Name    Count
Ram     4
Arjun   7
```

I tried groupby but I cannot achieve the desired output, please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by values of `Name`s converted to [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) - `first` and `sum`:

```
df = (df.groupby(df['Name'].str.lower(), as_index=False, sort=False)
        .agg({'Name':'first', 'Count':'sum'}))
print (df)
    Name  Count
0    Ram      4
1  Arjun      7
```

Detail:

```
print (df['Name'].str.lower())
0      ram
1      ram
2      ram
3    arjun
4    arjun
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: how to apply if its the values are in a same column

Comment: Hmmm, I have an idea. But question is if first row is `RAM     1` in data do you need ouput `Ram 4` ? Is possible `RAM a, Ram A, rAM a` values  and then output `Ram a 4` ?

Comment: so it seems you need `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['RAM a','ram a','ram a','raM a','Arjun','Arjun','Arjun','arjun','arjun','arjun','arjun']})` - `
a = df1['Name'].groupby(df1['Name'].str.title()).size().reset_index(name='Count')` or `a = df1['Name'].groupby(df1['Name'].str.capitalize()).size().reset_index(name='Count')`

Answer (score 3):

```
In [71]: df.assign(Name=df['Name'].str.capitalize()).groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()
Out[71]:
    Name  Count
0  Arjun      7
1    Ram      4
```

Answer (score 3):

If I group by `title` formatted strings, it simplifies the steps I must take.

```
df.Count.groupby(df.Name.str.title()).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can you pls check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096797/how-to-match-a-word-in-a-datacolumn-with-a-list-of-values-and-applying-ignorecas